# HTTP-заголовки: для чего нужны и в каких случаях примееняются?

Tags: http

Добрый день!
Трудно дается мне тема http-заголовков,обьясните пожалуйста  для чего нужны 
вот эти заголовки и в каких случаях применяется вот этот набор заголовков.

```
 header('Content-type:text/html; charset=windows-1251');//
 header("Expires:",date("r"));
 header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s')."GMT");
 header('Cache-Control:no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate');//Этот я понял кэширует
```

Comment: хм

    ping google.com
    
    Обмен пакетами с google.com [173.194.32.3] с 32 байтами данных:
    Ответ от 173.194.32.3: число байт=32 время=97мс TTL=49
    Ответ от 173.194.32.3: число байт=32 время=104мс TTL=49
    Ответ от 173.194.32.3: число байт=32 время=124мс TTL=49
    Ответ от 173.194.32.3: число байт=32 время=180мс TTL=49
    
    Статистика Ping для 173.194.32.3:
     Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 4, потеряно = 0
    (0% потерь)
    Приблизительное время приема-передачи в мс:
    Минимальное = 97мсек, Максимальное = 180 мсек, Среднее = 126 мсек

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поработаю Гуглом (должен будет)

```
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=windows-1251');
```

Здесь PHP говорит что выдача это страница ХТМЛ в морально устаревшей кодировке cp1251.

```
header("Expires:",date("r"));
```

Дата в каком-то там общепринятом формате, означает, что страница устарела на момент ее создания (время устарения == время создания).

```
header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s')."GMT");
```

Последний раз страница изменилась когда была отдана в браузер.

```
header('Cache-Control:no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate');
```

Да, это чтобы не кэшировалось. Парой слов не сказать- все уже сказано здесь http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Подводим итог: один заголовок, чтобы определить содержание и три заголовка, чтобы сказать браузеру, что страницу нельзя кэшировать.

Answer (score 0):

Это просто заголовки, которые включают или выключают кеширование на клиенте. Т.е. они говорят браузеру посетителя - стоит ли ему отправлять (и когда стоит) повторные запросы на одни и те же ссылки.

Полезно - инструмент для проверки [Cache-control](http://highloadtools.com/cachecontrol) и установка/запрет [кеширования в PHP](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+Cache-control+%D0%B2+PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете автоматически проверить HTTP-заголовки своего сайта через [сервис проверки HTTP-заголовков](https://http.itsoft.ru) по всем версиям протокола HTTP для любых методов запроса и любых заголовков запроса. Там будут и предупреждения на что обратить внимание и ошибки.

Собственно, а дальше просто добавляйте или правьте соответствующие заголовки либо в .htaccess либо в php-скриптах через headers(...);

Совсем длинная [статья по настройке HTTP-заголовков](https://itsoft.ru/data-center/faq/linux/install-apache/headers/), если нужно вникнуть в детали.